# Prediction based on posterior distribution

Tags: statistics

I am now working on this problem.
Suppose a biased coin has probability $\theta$ to give heads.
Suppose the prior of $\theta$ is of uniform distribution$(0,1)$.
With observed information, in $n$ trials the coin gives $r$ heads.
The question asks for the probability of next flip being a head.

Attempts: an earlier proof I learnt gives an integral formula to compute posterior prediction density if given posterior distribution and $f(X_{n+1}|\;\theta)$

I can't understand the latter term: $f(X_{n+1} |\; \theta)$
I read the material here from page 16 :http://www.markirwin.net/stat220/Lecture/Lecture4.pdf

I think I am on the right way, but even though I can find the posterior distribution, how does this lead me to find out the actual probability the result of next flip?

Many thanks. Much appreciated. xD

Comment: $f(X_{n+1} \text{"given"} \theta)$ means that you know $\theta$ so you can use conditional probability

Comment: I can't find any $f(X_{n+1}|\theta)$ in the document you linked to. I think it would be best if you quote that integral formula you refer to; that would make it easier to see what $f(X_{n+1}|\theta)$ refers to.

Comment: The formula on p.16 is for the predictive distribution. What exactly don't you understand there?

Comment: Xn+1 in this question means the next observation--the future prediction.

Comment: so instead of "any" future prediction in the document(written y hat there),the question calls it Xn+1 as there were n trials before, giving ovservations x1,x2,x3,...,xn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability to observe the $(n+1)$th result $x$ in $\{0,1\}$ after $n$ first results with sum $r$ is $p_x$ with
$$
p_x\propto\int_0^1\theta^r(1-\theta)^{n-r}\theta^x(1-\theta)^{1-x}\mathrm d\theta\propto(r+x)!(n-r+1-x)!.
$$
Thus,
$$
p_1=\frac{r+1}{n+2},\qquad p_0=1-p_1.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your kindness on helping my stupid question TT

Comment: would you please explain the meaning of little x in Px? I guess it's a kind of probability. How would this x be applied on the power of (1-THETA)? Shouldn't the powers be number of trials?

Comment: Note that $p^x(1-p)^{1-x}$ is $p$ when $x=1$ and $1-p$ when $x=0$.